# Liferay roles and permissions for publishing

Tags: permissions, liferay-6, roles

I am new to Liferay, since there are many roles in Liferay, i'm in confusion.

I need to implement a particular scenario like,

Admin --> can publish

Users(under admin) --> can edit content and make request to admin for publishing

can any one explain how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below link for detail explanation of "Liferay workflow for Web Content".

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-liferays-workflow-with-wcm-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-02-en